# How to remove special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have copied text "Revisions Analysis Dataset – Infra-annual Economic Indicators" from https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MEI_ARCHIVE and Exported to CSV file, but its showing some invalid characters "â€“" in csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['Revisions Analysis Dataset – Infra-annual Economic Indicators'])
df.to_csv(r"D:\Sunil_Work\temp.csv")
```

Special Characters found in Exported File as below:

```
0,Revisions Analysis Dataset â€“ Infra-annual Economic Indicators
```

I have included **encoding = 'utf-8'**, but no luck, Please help on this.

```
df.to_csv(r"D:\Sunil_Work\temp.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you add on which line you are finding this Issue, I just downloaded the dataset you linked and cannot find these characters.

Comment: Try using `encoding='utf-8-sig'` or `encoding='utf-16'`

Comment: anand_v.singh: From Dataset Name

Comment: @Suraj M, Great Thanks a lot, Its working fine, Add as answer pls

Comment: @anand_v.singh, how you downloaded, pls let me know

Comment: @Suraj M, Done. Thanks

Comment: @anand_v.singh, Thanks you can delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `utf-8` not working for all types of encoding.

Try below approaches:

1. `encoding=utf-8-sig`
2. `encoding=utf-16`